# Удалить все повторяющиеся элементы из списка. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list6 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

for i in list6:
   if i == i:
       list6.remove(i.__index__())
       print(list6)
```

Почему у меня в конце удаляет 5?

Я тут заметила что строка if i == i: ничего не меняет в коде. Так как мне решать это?

Comment: `if i == i:` Что с чем вы здесь хотите сравнить?

Comment: типо хочу понять в нём повторяются числи. если да то del

Comment: я не смотрела решений, хотела сама решить, подумала так сработает

Comment: попробуйте `set(list6)`

Comment: простите как, где?

Comment: @python_prog `list6 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] print(set(list6))`

Comment: list6 = list(set(list6)) - получите ваш список без дубликатов

Comment: Как именно проверка i==i проверяет повторы чисел?? i всегда равно i.

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!

Comment: Еще одно решение: `s = sorted(a); res = [s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if s[i] != s[i - 1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list(set([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]))
```

А у вашем случае надо написать как-то так: если в списке уже есть такой элемент, то идти к следующему и проверять снова.

```
duplicates = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
unique = duplicates[0:0]

for i in range(len(duplicates)):
    if duplicates[i] in unique: 
        continue
    unique.append(duplicates[i])

print(unique)
```

---

Либо, расписал более детально (но так делать ни в коем случае нельзя):

```
duplicates = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 0]
unique = []

# Проходимся по каждому элементу нашего списка
for i in range(len(duplicates)):
    # Заводим флаг, который обозначает, что такой элемент уже был
    contains = False

    # Теперь самая важная часть
    # Проходимся по тех всех элементах изначального списка начиная от того, на которым мы сейчас в главном цикле
    for j in range(i + 1, len(duplicates)):
        # Если текущий элемент главного цикла тот же, что и нашего вложенного, то понятно, что это повторение значения
        # Ставим флаг, что мы нашли совпадение
        if duplicates[i] == duplicates[j]: 
          contains = True

    # А тут проверяем, если совпадений не было, то это уникальный элемент и его можно добавить в выходной список
    if not contains:
      unique.append(duplicates[i])

print(unique)
```

Comment: Объясните  пожалуйста что означает эта строка unique = duplicates[0:0]

Comment: @python_prog итерация по списку от нулевого индекса до нулевого индекса не включительно, то есть просто присвоить переменной пустой список.

Comment: @python_prog мы берем первый элемент с массива duplicates и запихиваем его в массив. Если будет к примеру `[1, 2, 3, 4][0:0]` то будет `[1]`

Comment: Спасибо ребята!☻

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужно преобразовывать список в множество, а оставить его также списком, то можно завести счетчик символов и сделать так:

```
list6 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
counter = 0
for i in list6:
    counter += 1
    if counter >= 1:
        list6.remove(i)
print(list6)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: так у вас 5 пропадает

Comment: Да у меня тоже была такая проблема

Comment: Ой, точно, пардон

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить простой вариант решения:

```
list6 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list_res = [] # создаем список, в котором
                    # будут храниться уникальные элементы
for i in list6:
    if i not in list_res: # проверка на наличие элемента в списке
       list_res.append(i) # добавляем новый элемент
print(list_res)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```